# Python Framework - Tables GUI in Webapp

Tags: python, web-development, graphs, table

I am trying to write a webapp in Python. I know, why not use JS with React, but I don't want to learn JS at the moment (no time...) and want to get going with what I know about Python.

I tried to create a GUI with Kivy/KivyMD and PyQt, but they cannot be used for WebApps as it seems.

Possible seem: Flask, Anvil, Django.

As I want to work with databases a lot (especially display data from SQLite and also write into the SQLite file from the webpage) and create graphs (mathplotlib I guess), only Django seems usable, correct?

Do you think I can create a webpage that way or is it a waste of time and I should go learn JS+React? That is basically the reaction I got so far :)
However, why do these frameworks exist if they cannot be reasonably used for this purpose, right?

Anyway, let's assume Python is ok, which framework would you use for this kind of web development?